Why NX Eslint enforceBuildableLibDependency rule exists
So NX has some of its own eslint rules nx eslint rules docs, what is not immedaitly clear is one of those rules 'enforceBuildableLibDependency'. Why you have this implication/restriction for buildable libraries, why NX want to restrict import of 3th party libs inside buildable libs, they can't do it or they just want to restrict it what is the problem for buildable lib to import 3th party libs? Can someone explain why this restriction exists ?
PS If this "enforceBuildableLibDependency": false, rule is enabled in .eslintrc.base.json in your NX monorepo you will get this kind of error when your library is doing imports from 'node_modules'. Yes you can disable the esrule but the question remains why we have this limitation for nx buildable libraries in the first place.

ESLint: Buildable libraries cannot import or export from non-buildable
libraries(@nx/enforce-module-boundaries

PS I am using vite within NX as as build/bundle tool and I don't see why this limitation exists.

Did you ever come around a proper explanation?
